# Tab don't show up on Microsoft Teams Bot

Tags: botframework, bots, microsoft-teams, azure-cognitive-services

I followed this document [Add tabs to Microsoft Teams apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-overview) to add a static tab in personal scope for my Ms teams app which is nothing but a chatbot built based on botbuilder nodejs sdk. Here is how entry from manifest.json file looks

```
"staticTabs": [
    {
        "entityId": "spotify_g",
        "name": "Show Spotify home page",
        "contentUrl": "https://www.spotify.com/us/",
        "websiteUrl": "https://www.spotify.com/us/",
        "scopes": [
            "personal"
        ]
    }
]
```

I am just trying show spotify home page for fun to try out this functionality so later I can embed my website's home page. But, for some reason I don't see anything when Tab is clicked on the installed Bot. Looks like its not rendering in an . Any thoughts ?

Screen Shot can be found [here](https://ibb.co/GcJh1ZG)w where is shows nothing is rendering on the tab.

Comment: Are you wanting the tab to open or be available specifically as a feature of your Teams app (bot)? If not, could you just add a (website) tab for Spotify?

Comment: I just want to serve some useful information about the Bot (may be list is skills / features ) etc to user so I thought static tab is right way to go where I can just embed static webPage. 
How to add a website) tab ? I see only 2 options in App Studio. 1) Static and 2) Team tab.

Comment: @StevenKanberg, I forgot to mention is even though this BOT is Ms team app its only for 1:1 conversations. People don't use it in their teams channel. in case this helps in your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spotify doesn't allow themselves to be iframed by Teams. Here are console logs:
[image]
Try putting this URL for testing: https://www.bing.com/maps/embed

Best way to debug tabs would be by opening Microsoft Teams in web client and looking at console logs. Please have a look at documentation on [how do tabs in Teams differ from a browser viewing the same content URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-overview?view=msteams-client-js-latest#how-do-tabs-in-teams-differ-from-a-browser-viewing-the-same-content-url).